# Replace a ruby regular expression pattern with a variation of that pattern, within a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string: `"@OKFN @417_tw The _European Commission; && _European Governments; are consulting on Open Research Data; read our response: http://blog.okfn.org/2013/07/16/ec-consultation-on-open-research-data"` and i want to replace all couples of words preceded by "_" and ended with ";" by the same words but without those characters.

Here's how i did it, but i dont think its very neat. Would there be a better way to do it?

```
subj="@OKFN @417_tw The _European Commission; && _European Governments; are consulting on Open Research Data; read our response: http://blog.okfn.org/2013/07/16/ec-consultation-on-open-research-data"

tags=subj.scan(/_[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+;/)

tags.each do |t|
    t.gsub!(/_|;/,"")
    subj.sub!("_"+t+";",t)

end

puts subj
```

Comment: i want to remove "_" and ";" but not in all ocurrencies

Comment: *but not in all ocurrencies* means ? give us a sample short string and the expected output from that string. Myself at-least not getting the point of yours.

Comment: not in 417_tw for instance, just when its 2 words, the first one preceded by "_" and the last one ended in ";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you describe:

```
subj.gsub(/_([^_;]*);/, '\1')
```

If you just want to delete `"_"` and `";"`, then this:

```
subj.tr("_;", "")
```

Comment: this is removing "_" from the twitter user @417_tw